# iOS 11 split screen doesn’t work on iPad mini?

Tags: ios, ipad, beta-seed-program, split-view, beta

I’m running iOS 11 on an old iPad mini. When I open slide over, it works fine. But when I try dragging down or up on the tab, split screen doesn’t work.

Am I doing it wrong? Or is it just not compatible with iPad minis? I think it would be a useful feature and I’m bummed that it’s not working.

Slide over:
[image]

When I drag down:
[image]

When I drag up:
[image]

EDIT: it is model A1474 on iOS 11.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A1474 is a first-generation iPad Air, not an iPad mini.

The first generation iPads do not support Split View.

> You can use Split View with iPad Pro, iPad (5th generation), iPad Air 2, or iPad mini 4.

[Use two apps at the same time with Split View - Use Multitasking on your iPad](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207582)

Slide Over is supported on the first generation iPad Air, but not first generation iPad mini, once again reinforcing that you have an iPad Air and not an iPad mini.

> You can use Slide Over with iPad Pro, iPad (5th generation), iPad Air and later, or iPad mini 2 and later.

[Open a second app with Slide Over - Use Multitasking on your iPad](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207582)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I’m curious, why did Apple choose not to support it?